# C++ template 'length' metafunction error

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming

I'm currently trying to write a length metafunction for a list implementation I've been writing but having a few issues. Here is my current implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, T N>
struct type_ {
  using type = type_<T, N>;
  using value_type = T;
  static constexpr T value = N;
  using next = type_<T, N + 1>;
  using prev = type_<T, N - 1>;
};

template <int N>
struct int_ : type_<int, N> {
  using type = int_<N>;
};

struct empty {
  using type = empty;
  using value = empty;
};

template <typename car, typename cdr>
struct cons {
  using type = cons<car, cdr>;
  using value = car;
  using next = cdr;
};

struct cdr_f {
  template <typename cons>
  struct apply {
    using type = typename cons::next::type;
  };
};

template <typename cons>
struct cdr : cdr_f::template apply<cons> {};

struct car_f {
  template <typename cons>
  struct apply {
    using type = typename cons::type::value;
  };
};

template <typename cons>
struct car : car_f::template apply<cons> {};

struct length_f {
  template <typename list>
  struct apply : std::conditional<
    std::is_same<typename car<list>::type, empty>::value,
    int_<0>,
    int_<1 + length_f::template apply<typename cdr<list>::type>::value>
  > {};
};

int main() {
  std::cout << std::is_same<
    typename car<empty>::type,
    empty
  >::value << std::endl; // prints 1.
  std::cout << length_f::template apply<empty>::type::value <<  std::endl; // should print 0.
  return 0;
}
```

When applying `length_f::template apply<empty>` I get the following error:

> error: no member named 'next' in 'meta::list::empty'

I've been at this for a couple hours now and what I think is happening is for some reason `std::is_same<typename car<list>::type, empty>::value` is returning false, however doing some tests it seems that true is returned when evaluating `car<empty>::type`. Having `cdr<empty>::type` return a compiler error is expected but it shouldn't be able to reach that point since the conditional is in place.

I'm using Apple's clang-602.0.53 if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: FYI this compiles cleanly with both g++ and clang once I fill in the missing blanks. `clang-602.0.53` doesn't look like a standard clang version designation. I have tested with clang-3.5.1, the current version available for download is 3.6.1.

Comment: Updated the post to include a fully reproducible example. :) Also, I'm using Apple's clang: `$ g++ -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
Thread model: posix`

Comment: A side note, it is not entirely clear why you are checking for car(list)==empty rather than list==empty. The former check makes no sense. An empty list has no car, and a car of a list is not necessary a list itself.

Comment: I think your issue is that you expect the not-taken branch of std::conditional to remain unevaluated, much like an if statement in conventional languages. This expectation doesn't seem to have any foundation. You need to delay evaluation explicitly, or alternatively use a nonsense value for cdr(empty), perhaps void.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you, the solution turned out to be changes in a few places but it was essentially a problem with `std::conditional` not being lazy. Also, the car(list) thing was just a remnant of my sad attempts to try and get _something_ to work. hah. Post your comments as an answer and I'd be happy to accept it.